# Question regarding derivative and measures

Tags: integration, measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-measure, signed-measures

Here's what I need to show:

Let $\mu$ be any finite signed Borel measure on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Let $g: [-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb R$ be defined by $g(\theta ) = \int_{0}^{\theta} d\mu (t)$ if $\theta >0$ and $g(\theta ) = -\int_{\theta}^{0} d\mu (t)$ if $\theta <0$. Prove that $d\mu = g' d\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on $[-\pi,\pi]$.

---

I am not entirely sure to how to proceed but here's my attempt:

We need to prove that $\mu (A)=\int_{A} g' d\lambda$ for every Borel set $A$. I tried to write $g'(x)= \lim_{n\to 0} \frac{g(x+1/n) - g(x)}{1/n}$. I tried to use Fubini theorem to complete the proof but I am not getting what I desire. Hints would be appreciated!

---

NOTE: This result may or may not be true! I made this claim in order to justify the proof of Fatou's theorem in Koosis - Introduction to $H_p$ spaces.

I want to show that $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} P_r (t) d\mu(t) = P_r(\pi)g(\pi)-P_r(-\pi)g(-\pi)-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\partial_t P_r (t) g(t) dt$, where $P_r$ is the Poisson kernel, which is essentially integration by parts. I know this result holds for absolutely continuous functions but I was generalising this statement. Any hints to prove this will be appreciated!

Comment: First of all, when working with measures the notation $\int_a^b$ is often not ideal is it might mean $\int_{(a,b)}$, $\int_{[a,b]}$ or anything in between. This isn't a problem for the Lebesgue measure as $\{a,b\}$ is a zero set, but this might not be the case for $\mu$.

Comment: @n3u1r0n you're right. I should have been a little more careful. I borrowed this notation from the book: Koosis - Introduction to $H_p$ spaces. I am not sure what the author means at this point.

Comment: I doubt that result.  Can't there be a (signed) measure that is not absolutely continuous?  And even if $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $[-\pi,\pi]$ I think you have a sign wrong in there.

Comment: @GEdgar I have updated the description. Please take a look.

Comment: What you probably actually want is
$$
g(\theta)=
\begin{cases}
-\int_{[\theta,0)}\mathrm{d}\mu,&\quad\theta<0\\
\ \ \ \int_{[0,\theta]}\mathrm{d}\mu,&\quad\theta\geq0.
\end{cases}
$$
Then you would like to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus on $A=(a,b)$ an interval, but this needs some restrictions on $\mu$ such that $g$ is differentiable for example.

Comment: @n3u1r0n Since $g$ is of bounded variation, it is differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: The conclusion you give holds only when $\mu$ (equivalently $g$) is absolutely continuous.

Comment: Take $\mu=\delta$ which assigns mass $0$ to everything except the point $0$. Then $g$ is a step function. Yes this $g$ is now differentiable almost everywhere, however the derivative is zero everywhere and your claim cannot hold.
Again, this is due to the possibility that $\mu$ has these point masses. Avoid them to avoid these headaches.